Cookies Not Being Set in Flask Application When Accessed via Domain but Work Locally
I'm running a python Flask application, using Waitress and apache to serve. I have configured HTTPS and can access my application via https://example.com
The problem is that cookies are not being set when accessed via my domain (https://example.com).
The cookies are correctly set and persisted when running locally.
I am using the below to set the cookie:
# Store shipment_id in session or pass to the template
session['shipment_id'] = shipment_id
print("Stored shipment ID in session:", session['shipment_id'])

The print statement is correctly displaying the shipment id but I can see from the browser developer tools that its not getting stored.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
